# How do I calculate the covarient derivative of a type (2,1) or (1,2) tensor

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

The following tensor I need help calculating the covarient derivative are as follows:

[image: Type (2,1) Tensor]

and

[image: Type (1,2) tensor]

I know the general rule when it comes to a type (0,2) tensor is

[image: General form (0,2) tensor]

and I know the general rule when it comes to a type (2,0) tensor is

[image: General form (2,0) tensor]

I just am not sure how to fully flush out the covarient derivatives for the (2,1) and (1,2) tensor

This is what I am getting from my own attempt

[image: Edited 1.0]

Comment: For each index up, you have a $+\Gamma$ term, and for each index down, you have a $-\Gamma$ term. So, why not write down your best guess for $\tau^{\,ab}_{c}$, and we can see if you're on the right track.

Comment: You can find the formulas in (e.g.) Proposition 4.18 in Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: @peek-a-boo i worked it out to the last picture in the edited question

Comment: You can immediately tell the answer is wrong because you should have indices $a, b$ on top and $c$ below.